# how to keep data consistent when using @RefreshScope in a execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I read this [Dynamic Configuration Properties in Spring Boot and Spring Cloud](https://gist.github.com/dsyer/a43fe5f74427b371519af68c5c4904c7)
And it said that

> If your method execution is the one that triggers the initialization,
>   then it all even happens in the same thread.

This is my code, a **TestConfigBean**:

```
 package com.my.springdemo.chapter3.test;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
@Data
@RefreshScope
public class TestConfig {
    @Value("${name}")
    private String name;

    @PostConstruct
    private void print(){
        System.out.println("配置为=" + name);
    }
}
```

**A controller**:

```
package com.my.springdemo.chapter3.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ContextRefresher;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@ConditionalOnClass(ContextRefresher.class)
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestConfig config;

    @Autowired
    private  ContextRefresher contextRefresher;

    @RequestMapping("/config")
    public String config(){
        System.out.println("before config= " + config.getName() + ", hasCode=" + config.hashCode());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        contextRefresher.refresh();
        System.out.println("After config= " + config.getName() + ", hasCode=" + config.hashCode());
        return config.getName();
    }

}
```

Then get url: http://localhost:8080/config, and changed config "*name*" in my "**application.properties**" during the thread sleep time(which id 10 seconds as the code shows).

It turns out that the config "*name*" is changed before and after.
Why?Does I take @RefreshScope the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the expected behavior of `@RefreshScope` bean. 
Like the document says

> Two consecutive method executions on the same bean in the same thread may be applied to different targets if things get really busy.

`@RefreshScope` bean doesn't guarantee that your multiple invocations on the same thread will use the same target bean.

In your sample, you call `contextRefresher.refresh();` and it will destroy all refresh scoped beans. And your second invocation of `config.getName()` will reinitialize your bean again. That's why you got the different name in case that you changed your config between your two invocations.

> If your method execution is the one that triggers the initialization, then it all even happens in the same thread.

Above statement just means that bean initialization itself will be executed on the same thread. It doesn't mean that your two invocations will use the same target.

IMHO, using `@RefreshScope` could be a little risky for certain cases.

**Update on the question in comments**

IMHO, `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation is also specially treated in Spring Cloud. If `EnvironmentChangedEvent` occurs, Spring beans that are annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` will be re-binded with changed values.

The main difference between `@ConfigurationProperties` in Spring Cloud and `@RefreshScope` bean is atomicity during the process.

Spring Cloud just starts rebinding process for `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated beans WITHOUT creating a new instance of bean when `EnvironmentChangedEvent` occurs. It means that any invocation into this bean can occur during this process (namely before this process ends). As a result, a user of this bean can see any intermediate state (ex three properties are changed. But two properties values are applied and one property are not yet applied. Any invocation can occur on this state)

In case of using `@RefreshScope` annotation, a proxy bean is created and it is injected instead of your actual target bean. And if the bean is refreshed (by an invocation of refresh() API or another way), your actual target bean is removed from the cache. If any next invocation to your bean occurs, your target bean is re-created and initialized again (and this process is synchronized by the lock). As a result, your any invocation to your bean always occurs on stable state of your bean (after finishing initializing beans)

You can annotation your `@ConfigurationProperties` bean with `@RefreshScope`. Or you can only use `@RefreshScope` annotation with your bean with `@Value` annotation on its internal fields.

Anyway, neither `@ConfigurationProperties` nor `@RefreshScope` can guarantee your expected result for multiple invocations even on the same thread. Hope this helps.

Comment: And if this is what RefreshScope does,then what's the diffrence between RefreshScope  and ConfigurationProperties.

Comment: I've updated my answer. That is all I know. I think that you need more tests to use this in your production.

Comment: Thank you very much.Your answer really helps me understand.Maybe I should do it in a different way instead  of depending on the spring-cloud framework.

Comment: Hi, yoon,now I know the RefreshScope bean acts as a proxy of a real target, can you give me a lead about where I can find the spring codes which make this behaviour works?I try to find the code but none.Thank you anyway!

Comment: I think that GenericScope (superclass of RefreshScope) could be a good starting point. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/1.3.x/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/GenericScope.java